# Animate two or more figures simultaneously with matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate two matplotlib figures at the same time. I wrote a script that creates two instances of matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation, but only one of them animates, the other remains static.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

x=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)

# Function for making figures
def makeFigure():
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    # Plot a line
    line,=ax.plot(x,np.sin(x))

    return fig,ax,line

# Frame rendering function
def renderFrame(i,line):
    # Apply a phase shift to the line
    line.set_data(x,np.sin(x-i*2*np.pi/100))
    return line,

# Make the figures
figcomps1=makeFigure()
figcomps2=makeFigure()

# Animate the figures
for figcomps in [figcomps1,figcomps2]:
    fig,ax,line=figcomps
    anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,renderFrame,fargs=[line])

plt.show()
```

Is FuncAnimation capable of animating two figures simultaneously? If not, is there another way to simultaneously animate two matplotlib figures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Cause of Issue

**You must track each `FuncAnimation` object separately** by holding reference to each individual object.

In your `for` loop, the `FuncAnimation` object is being instantiated twice (with name `anim`), and hence in the namespace, effectively 'overwritten'.

From the [Animation Module Docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html)

> ...it is critical to keep a reference to the instance object. The animation is advanced by a timer ... which the [Func]Animation object holds the only reference to. If you do not hold a reference to the [Func]Animation object, it (and hence the timers), will be garbage collected which will stop the animation.

### Example Solution

Instead, tracking both `FuncAnimation` objects in, for example a list of `FuncAnimation` objects, will allow them to both be animated with their own timers

```
#...

# List of Animation objects for tracking
anim = []

# Animate the figures
for figcomps in [figcomps1,figcomps2]:
    fig,ax,line=figcomps
    anim.append(animation.FuncAnimation(fig,renderFrame,fargs=[line]))
```

I wish to stress this is only an example, as there are many other methods of tracking multiple objects in a `for` loop, as explored in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674080/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-dynamically-create-class-instances)